# Can I transfer angular template from one component to another component with its value?

Tags: angular

How can I transfer the value of files to the service.The value of files is dynamic.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpRequest,
  HttpEventType, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, last, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {CommonService} from '../common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './material-file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material-file-upload.component.css']
})
export class MaterialFileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Link text */
  @Input() text = 'Upload';
  /** Name used in form which will be sent in HTTP request. */
  @Input() param: any;
  /** Target URL for file uploading. */
  @Input() target = '';
  /** File extension that accepted, same as 'accept' of <input type="file" />.
   By the default, it's set to 'image/*'. */
  @Input() accept = [];
  /** Allow you to add handler after its completion. Bubble up response text from remote. */
  @Output() complete = new EventEmitter<string>();
  public files: Array<FileUploadModel> = [];
  /*private files =  <FileUploadModel>{};*/
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private common: CommonService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick() {
    const fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload') as HTMLInputElement;
    fileUpload.onchange = () => {
      /*for (let index = 0; index < fileUpload.files.length; index++) {*/
      const file = fileUpload.files[0];
      this.files.push({ data: file, state: 'in',
        inProgress: false, progress: 0, canRetry: false, canCancel: true });
      // }
      this.uploadFiles();
      this.common.uploadProgress = this.files;
    };
    fileUpload.click();
  }

  cancelFile(file: FileUploadModel) {
    file.sub.unsubscribe();
    this.removeFileFromArray(file);
  }

  retryFile(file: FileUploadModel) {
    this.uploadFile(file);
    file.canRetry = false;
  }

  private uploadFile(file: FileUploadModel) {
    const fd = new FormData();
    // console.log('fileeeeee ', file.data);
    if (file.data.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.data.type === 'image/jpg' ||
        file.data.type === 'image/png' || file.data.type === 'image/gif') {
      console.log('imageeeeeeeeeee');
      fd.append('image', file.data);
    } else {
      fd.append('video', file.data);
    }

    // this.param.map(index =>{
    //   console.log(index);
    //   fd.append(this.param.key(index), this.param.value(index));
    // });
    /*for (var key in this.param) {
      fd.append(key, this.param[key]);
    }*/

    // console.log(fd);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.target, fd, {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    file.inProgress = true;
    file.sub = this._http.request(req).pipe(
        map(event => {
          switch (event.type) {
            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
              file.progress = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
              break;
            case HttpEventType.Response:
              return event;
          }
        }),
        tap(message => { }),
        last(),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          file.inProgress = false;
          file.canRetry = true;
          return of(`${file.data.name} upload failed.`);
        })
    ).subscribe(
        (event: any) => {
          if (typeof (event) === 'object') {
            this.removeFileFromArray(file);
            this.complete.emit(event.body);
          }
        }
    );
  }

  private uploadFiles() {
    const fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload') as HTMLInputElement;
    fileUpload.value = '';

    this.files.forEach(file => {
      this.uploadFile(file);
    });
  }

  private removeFileFromArray(file: FileUploadModel) {
    const index = this.files.indexOf(file);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.files.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

}

export class FileUploadModel {
  data: File;
  state: string;
  inProgress: boolean;
  progress: number;
  canRetry: boolean;
  canCancel: boolean;
  sub?: Subscription;
}
```

I want to transfer full div element to another component. I'm created a component for upload image and use it to another component. But I can't show image after upload.

```html
<button (click)="onClick()">
  <img src="assets/images/videoupload.png" alt="">
</button>
  <div *ngFor="let file of files">
    <mat-progress-spinner [diameter]="28" [color]="'warn'" class="progress" [value]="file.progress"></mat-progress-spinner>
    <span id="file-label">
           {{file.data.name}}
      <a title="Retry" (click)="retryFile(file)" *ngIf="file.canRetry">
            <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon></a>
            <a title="Cancel" (click)="cancelFile(file)" *ngIf="file.canCancel">
            <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon></a>
            </span>
  </div>


<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" accept="{{accept}}" style="display:none;"/>
```

I want to use hole div into another component, in a particular position.

Comment: please share your code here. so that we can help you.

Comment: Store information about uploaded file in service and get information from service as I write in answer.

Comment: I can't transfer data to the service

Comment: Why you can`t? Better to put your upload logic from component into some uploadFile.service.ts and in this file create fields, which store all data what you need. In component just leave the logic to interact with client interface and connect with service

Comment: Can I call function of one component from another component?

Comment: Yes. Read this article https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction But in your case, in my opinion, better to create service

Comment: If you want to build a generic file-upload component, where each application individually decides how it presents this information to the user, you just have to leverage the power of angular templates. [Here's a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uaxb5r?file=src%2Fmain.ts) I built some time ago. No service is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), where you can manage your data and state of your component or application in common.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to leverage the power of the routing.
create a same route on your routing module , but provide it with some id.
and then navigate to  a particular id where you want to navigate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!